# How do I set "-webkit-transition-timing-function" with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, webkit, css

How do I set "-webkit-transition-timing-function" with Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Use `element.style.webkitTransitionTimingFunction = 'value';`

Comment: I learned this the hard way but the `w` of webkit should be Upper case. Same goes for Moz and O.
Webkit and Moz seem to alias things so the lowercase version works as well, but opera doesnt. And the spec leans towards a capital

Answer (score 1):

Webkit can be lower case or upper case. No difference.